# Styling a submit button using CSS and images

Tags: html, css, button, submit, input-button-image

i want to make and style submit buttons i.e.

> input type="submit" style="buttonClass">

using CSS and provided images, that works on both hover as well as normal state, however i'm unable to reach the desired output.
I created the buttons using anchor tags and span which are perfect but i want the same look and feel for submit buttons also.
PS: i cannot use the moz and webtooolkit of css3 as my target browser will be IE7 and IE 8, and further i have to use the client provided images only.Is there any way around for submit button`<input type="submit">` to reach the desired output just similar to the buttons as created using the anchor buttons `<a><span></span></a>`?

[image: Left]
[image: Right]

HTML AS IS

```
 <a class="buttonImage" href="javascript:blankCheck('Approve');"><span> <bean:message key="button.common.submit"/> </span></a>
```

HTML TO BE

```
<input type="submit" class="buttonImage">
```

CSS AS IS for buttons using anchor

```
.buttonImage span  {
    background:  url('common/images/LeftButton.png') no-repeat 0 0; display: block;                                                                                                     
    line-height: 14px; padding: 7px 0 5px 8px; color: #1b1d60;
            }   
.buttonImage     
{
background:  url('common/images/RightButton.png') no-repeat top right; 
display: block;    float: left; height: 26px; margin-right: 6px; 
  padding-right: 7px; text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
   font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;
}

.buttonImage:hover span {
background-position: 0 -26px; color: #fff;
 }
.buttonImage:hover {
background-position: right -26px;
}
```

[image: right image]
[image: left]

Answer (score 0):

***[Live Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/B03kt99A)***

Hi now change to **some properties** your `css stylesheet` or `add two div in your anchor tag`

**as like this**

Please check to this

**Css**

```
.buttonImage{
display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.buttonImage .left_img  {
    background:  url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/634e1.png') no-repeat 0 0;
 float:left;    line-height: 15px; padding: 7px 0 5px 8px; color: #1b1d60;
}   
.right_img{
background:  url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyeSO.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  float:left;   height: 27px;
  width:7px;
}
.buttonImage:hover .left_img, .buttonImage:hover .right_img{
background-position:0 -26px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="buttonImage" href="javascript:blankCheck('Approve');">
  <span class="left_img"> <bean:message key="button.common.submit"/>Hello this is coding 
  </span>
  <span class="right_img"></span>
</a>
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/B03kt99A)***

Comment: Thanx rohit, but i think i missed the point in my question that i need to style the <input type="submit"> buttons, so please provide your inputs on my new query.Due to framework restrictions i am advised not to use buttons using <a><span></a>